# When I refresh or start the site, the image of the image slider is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I refresh or start my website, the first image isn't shown. Also on my mobile device I see all the images of my image slide. When I scroll through my image slider, everything works great. How can I fix that my first image is shown, and on a mobile device I see only one image and not all 3. I have also a navbar, maybe the css of that part doesn't go well with the css of the image slider.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <!--<img src="images/logo-groot.png" style="width:100%">-->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470104240373-bc1812eddc9f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDF8NnNNVmpUTFNrZVF8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Nieuw!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <!--<img src="images/vpersie.jpg" style="width:100%">-->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431440869543-efaf3388c585?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDJ8NnNNVmpUTFNrZVF8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <!--<img src="images/logo-klein.png" style="width:100%">-->
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611337473718-a2959f0004f8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDIyfDZzTVZqVExTa2VRfHxlbnwwfHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be because the image takes too long to load.

Comment: I tried a smaller image but it doesn't work